# Vlookup with Hlookup wrong cell value (Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm trying to use VLOOKUP with HLOOKUP to extract a value from table but it always give me wrong cell - offset the cell value by one -

[image: 1]

The equation is

`=VLOOKUP(G22,A5:Z18,HLOOKUP(H22,B3:Z4,1,FALSE),FALSE)`

the cell in red rec. is the right answer, but it always return value in green circle
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Without a pc, but try,  `=VLOOKUP(G22,A5:Z18,H22+1,FALSE)`. Either way, your VLOOKUP starts it's count in the A-column, not in B, so just add 1.

Comment: The HLookup is pointless.  You are saying 'Find the 6 in a table of integers and then return it unaltered'.  You might as well pass in H22 without alteration.  Maybe instead of HLookup you want `Match(H22, A3:Z3,0)` ?

Comment: After Chris' comment most effective final version (in order to prevent possible misuses in future) could be: `=VLOOKUP(G22,$A$5:$Z$18,Match(H22, $A$3:$Z$3,0),FALSE)`.    Plus, you better search the meaning of `$` sign in formula if you dont know it.

Comment: Tips: 1) get rid of rows 1, 2, and 4. If you ever sort this table you will thank me. One header row is all any table needs. 2) consider moving rows 21-22 to another sheet. These are more like UI, they are not data. 3) if you plan to use vlookups like this on larger sheets be sure to read up on Excel dependency tree update precedence and how to optimize, and be sure to paste values whenever possible.

Comment: To search an intersection of both horizontal and vertical matching values I recommend using INDEX/MATCH/MATCH: `=INDEX(B5:Z18,MATCH(G22,A5:A18,0),MATCH(H22,B3:Z3,0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### INDEX/MATCH Over VLOOKUP or HLOOKUP

[image]

- As a rule of thumb, using `HLOOKUP` only makes sense if you have more rows and you want to return a value from any but the first row. Similarly using `VLOOKUP` only makes sense if you have more columns and you want to return a value from any but the first column.
- A more flexible handling of lookups is achieved by using `INDEX` with `MATCH`.

  ```
  =INDEX(A3:Z18,MATCH(G22,A3:A18,0),MATCH(H22,A3:Z3,0))
  ```
- If someone enters `3` in `G22`, an error will be displayed. A simple way of error handling is using the `IFERROR` function.

  ```
  =IFERROR(INDEX(A3:Z18,MATCH(G22,A3:A18,0),MATCH(H22,A3:Z3,0)),"")
  ```
- Study the image closely. When it comes to finding **exact matches**, I never use `VLOOKUP` or `HLOOKUP` because `INDEX` with `MATCH` covers it all and more. That doesn't mean that you should abandon using them because they are good tools to get familiar with indexes, offsets, and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365, you can use Xlookup as described in Example 5 of [This reference](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929). Note that Xlookup can return a whole column from a 2d array:

```
=XLOOKUP(G22,A5:A18,XLOOKUP(H22,B3:K3,B5:K18))
```

or if the data is in fact a table where the Phi is the first column and the mm are the headers, this would be:

```
=XLOOKUP(G22,Table1[φ],XLOOKUP(H22,Table1[#Headers],Table1))
```

*Note* If the mm are in the headers, they are formatted as text so H22 has to be formatted to reflect this or use

```
=XLOOKUP(G22,A5:A18,XLOOKUP(TEXT(H22,"general"),B3:K3,B5:K18))
```

and

```
=XLOOKUP(G22,Table1[φ],XLOOKUP(TEXT(H22,"general"),Table1[#Headers],Table1))
```

[image]